# portable way of inserting DWORD into std::vector of WORD's

Tags: c++, vector, endianness

I stumbled upon following code snippet that inserts `DWORD` values into a `std::vector<WORD>`:

```
std::vector<WORD> memdlg;

DWORD exStyle = 0;
memdlg.push_back(LOWORD(exStyle));
memdlg.push_back(HIWORD(exStyle));

DWORD style = DS_CENTER | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | DS_SETFONT;
memdlg.push_back(LOWORD(style));
memdlg.push_back(HIWORD(style));
```

I understand what the code does, however this approach seems like not portable way in my opinion, because inserting low word first and then high word afterwards looks like this implies little endianness? am I correct about this assumption?

For example for big endian machine it should be the oposite:

```
memdlg.push_back(HIWORD(style));  // high word first
memdlg.push_back(LOWORD(style));  // low word second
```

Is this correct? because if later we(or other code accessing memory of the vector by index) want to extract `DWORD` out of a vector how to tell is ordering is correct for given platform?

BTW. vector needs to `WORD` vector, because calling code works with `WORDS` not `DWORDS`

Comment: interesting but, `MAKELONG` takes low word high word params, how do we know which is low word high word? I mean this implies that low word goes first, because the oposite would make `MAKELONG` produce bad result?

Comment: ok, I see, thanks for input.

Comment: *how do we know which is low word high word?*  The LOWORD means that if you take a value, you get the least significant WORD portion of the value, similarly with HIWORD, the most significant portion of the value.   An example -- LOWORD(1234) will be the same, regardless of the machine.